# C# How to set Property with two arguments

Tags: c#, properties

I need to setup a Property with **two** *arguments*, for example, to append text in a log file.
Example:

```
public string LogText(string text, bool Overwrite)
{
    get
    {
        return ProgramLogText;
    }
    set
    {
        ProgramLogText = value;
    }
}
```

How do I do this?
(in the example above, I need to pass the text I want to be written in the file and 1 to overwrite (0 as default value for appending the text), else append to a text file, but when I get, I just need the text.)

Comment: Why a property and not a method?

Comment: That's not possible for properties. Use a method for this.

Comment: That's not something you can do using a property. You _could_ encapsulate the two arguments into a class or struct instead and use that in your property, but a method would be _much_ better suited to this scenario (or perhaps a combination of a method to set the value and a property to read it, depending on your requirements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can *extract class* - implement your own `class` (`struct`) with `Text` and `Overwrite` properties and add some *syntax sugar*:

```
 public struct MyLogText {
   public MyLogText(string text, bool overwrite) {
     //TODO: you may want to validate the text
     Text = text;
     Overwrite = overwrite; 
   }

   public string Text {get;}  
   public bool Overwrite {get;}   

   // Let's add some syntax sugar: tuples
   public MyLogText((string, bool) tuple)
     : this(tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2) { }

   public void Deconstruct(out string text, out bool overwrite) {
     text = Text;
     overwrite = Overwrite;
   }

   public static implicit operator MyLogText((string, bool) tuple) => new MyLogText(tuple);

   //TODO: You may want to add ToString(), Equals, GetHashcode etc. methods
 }
```

And now you can put an easy syntax

```
public class MyClass {
  ...
  public MyLogText LogText {
    get;
    set;  
  }
  ...
}
```

And easy assignment (as if we have a property with **2** values):

```
MyClass demo = new MyClass();

// Set two values in one go
demo.LogText = ("some text", true);

// Get two values in one go 
(string text, bool overWrite) = demo.LogText;
```

Comment: Just a thing, it's because I am novice: I have another class, so I try to implement the above. I created the autoproperty inside a new public class with nothing else in it, but when I try the LogText = ("something", true); I got the "The name LogText does not exist in current context" - any advice?

Comment: @Nick: it seems that your call the property outside of the class; you probably, have to create the instance `MyClass demo = new MyClass();` etc. I've changed my example of usage.

Comment: Yes, you were correct of course. Thank you very much, worked perfectly.

Comment: nobody would think of a solution like this. Kudos to @DmitryBychenko.. However noone should ever try to write files lightly inside enormous obfuscation that the solution above actually is. one thing is to set fields in a "fancy way" and another is to access external unmanaged resources..

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

However, you have a few possible alternative approaches: create a method, or use a Tuple instead or create a class/struct and pass as a parameter (which has been answered by someone else).

Below are some alternative methods that can also be used instead.

**Alternative Method 1**

Create a Tuple, but then you'd have to return a tuple string, bool.

```cs
public Tuple<string, bool> LogText { get; set; }
```

I wouldn't do this method because then your getter would also return two values.

**Alternative Method 2**

Create getter and setter methods instead.

```cs
public string GetLogText() => ProgramLogText;
public void SetLogText(string text, bool overwrite) => ProgramLogText = text; // and implement in this method your use of overwrite.
```